# how do u use withdraw function after deployment of smart contract?

Tags: blockchain

I am a newbie here trying to understand smart contract. So when user transacts, money goes to the contract and then how do we call the withdraw function to withdraw the money? Can this done on front end or via truffle / hardhat?

Comment: wait! When you transact then money does not go to the contract. The user should explicitly send ether additional to the transaction fees

Comment: The contract should have a withdrawal function implemented and in that function you can write logic like withdrawals ether only to the owner of the contract or something else

Comment: I have this but it is still going to my contract when I test it. Do you know why? :(

Comment: we need to see the code and the problem :) sry cannot help alot you without it.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/110101/cant-seem-to-withdraw-money-from-contract I posted the code here. Appreciate the help!